# ListView hides after screen rotation

Tags: android, listview, rotation, onrestoreinstancestate

I'm confused about how to organize save-restoring process Activity state for ListView. I did it for one TextView that's worked without anything problem. I can't find an example to understand how ListView behaves.

I tried to save ArrayList, save Adapter state and then restore but nothing worked. Rest things work correctly.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int GOODS_REQUEST = 1;


private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //creating Array list which will be populate returned Goods
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //creating "Adapter" which behaves as a middleman between the data source and the layout
    // retrieves the data and converts each entry into a view that can be added into the layout
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_goods);
    //Sets the adapter that provides the data and the views to represent the data in this widget.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Restoring Activity instance state
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        arrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("received_goods");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


//event handler
public void addGoods(View view) {
    Intent openGoodsList = new Intent(this, GoodsList.class);
    startActivityForResult(openGoodsList, GOODS_REQUEST);
}

//receiving Goods
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GOODS_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        String goods = data.getStringExtra(GoodsList.EXTRA_GOODS);
        arrayList.add(goods);
        //Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
        // Use the method every time the list is updated.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

//saving Activity instance state
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("received_goods", arrayList);
}
```

Need explanation how ListView behaves in a save-restore process or an example which shows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrayList instance changed when you called 'savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("received_goods")', it is now different from array list instance that in adapter, You should do this way:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null){
    ArrayList<String> tmp= savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("received_goods");
    arrayList.addAll(tmp);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: It works thanks. But I didn't quite understand why we use tmp ArrayList.

Comment: When you called arrayList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("received_goods"); you changed the instance of arrayList to different instance, but arraylist that inside adapter is the original object and haven't been changed.